# Jump to definition in Python using static code analysis

Tags: filetype-python

I wonder if there is a way to jump to Python method definition in VIM using static code analysis (as described in https://gist.github.com/igemnace/dfa545d0d71228e010876d48a420a50b).

For example, if I have two files `base.py`:

```
class MyBase:
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')
```

and `bar.py`:

```
class MyClass(MyBase):
    def bar(self):
        self.foo()   # How to jump to base.py:MyBase:foo having cursor here
        print('bar')
```

How to jump to `base.py:MyBase:foo` definition from `bar.py:MyClass:bar` without having to choose correct place from ctags list?

Comment: It seems that [jedi-vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim) has this feature, found out from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32795794/2609806

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to join the LSP fandom you could install a client like [LanguageClient](https://github.com/autozimu/LanguageClient-neovim) (the repo name is misleading, it works with Vim 8 too) and use Microsoft's [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) calling it as `pyright-langserver --stdio`. I have been using it recently and works like a charm. The best part is you get more than just jump to definition